How to remove all docker containers at once in windows
WC:\Users\shbindal\Documents\aws\Devops\Ex_Files_Learning_Docker\New folder>docker ps -aq | xargs docker stop | xargs docker rm
'xargs' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Users\shbindal\Documents\aws\Devops\Ex_Files_Learning_Docker\New folder>docker ps -q | % { docker rm $_ }
'%' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Users\shbindal\Documents\aws\Devops\Ex_Files_Learning_Docker\New folder>docker rm $(docker ps -aq)
unknown shorthand flag: 'a' in -aq)
See 'docker rm --help'.

C:\Users\shbindal\Documents\aws\Devops\Ex_Files_Learning_Docker\New folder>

Was not able to remove all containers at once

This answer describes docker system prune, which doesn't require Unix Bourne shell pipes.

You can do this with powershell assuming your Docker installation is in Windows.
docker ps -aq | ForEach-Object { docker stop $_ }
docker ps -aq | ForEach-Object { docker rm $_ }

To do both in one step:
docker ps -aq | ForEach-Object { docker stop $_; docker rm $_ }

